# Is this a Swift closure?

Tags: ios, swift

I don't understand the `== false` part, the syntax looks like a closure but I can't find explanation in the Apple document.

```
let photoInfos = (JSON.value!.valueForKey("photos") as! [NSDictionary]).filter({
        ($0["nsfw"] as! Bool) == false
    }).map {
        PhotoInfo(id: $0["id"] as! Int, url: $0["image_url"] as! String)
    }
```

Is the first closure a closure?

Comment: It's a closure using shorthands for argument names (`$0` is the first argument, `$1` is the second one, etc...) and implied return value (it returns the result of that boolean expression)

Comment: It's terrible code is all it is. You should never compare a Boolean to true or false where a Boolean is expected.  It is already true or false.

Comment: Well, the code is from Raywenderlich ;)

Comment: @matt can you give a better example?

Comment: `!($0["nsfw"] as! Bool)`

Comment: Also you're using the word closure wrong. All Swift functions are closures. It's an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the `{ ($0["nsfw"] as! Bool) == false }` is a closure, it will filter the dictionary using this function (each element will take on the role of $0),  if the function evaluates to true it will be kept, if not it will not.

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FeRq_Ss14CollectionTypeq_Ss22_CollectionWrapperTypezqq_Ss9Indexable5Indexqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5Indexzqqq_S1_5IndexSs16ForwardIndexType8Distanceqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8Distancezqqq_S1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexzqqqq_S1_5IndexS2_8DistanceSs25IntegerLiteralConvertible18IntegerLiteralTypeqqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8DistanceS3_18IntegerLiteralType_SsS_6filteruRq_S_q_S0_zqq_S1_5Indexqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5Indexzqqq_S1_5IndexS2_8Distanceqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8Distancezqqq_S1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_19_DisabledRangeIndexzqqqq_S1_5IndexS2_8DistanceS3_18IntegerLiteralTypeqqqqq_S0_4BaseS1_5IndexS2_8DistanceS3_18IntegerLiteralType_Fq_FFqqqq_S0_4BaseSs12SequenceType9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSbGSaqqqq_S0_4BaseS4_9GeneratorS5_7Element_) to the doc on filter.

And here are a couple more examples of closures using filter and map.

```
// this one will filter the array by testing each element to see if the uppercased value matches the value, if so it is kept
let anArray = [ "a", "A", "b", "c"]
let aNewArray = anArray.filter { $0.uppercaseString == $0 }
print(aNewArray)  // prints the array ["A"]

// this one maps all the elements to their uppercase value    
let allUpcase = anArray.map { $0.uppercaseString }
print(allUpcase)  // "["A", "A", "B", "C"]
```